# DataTables warning: table id=datatable - Ajax error. Using laravel

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel, datatables

I am using jquery ajax datatable. I dont know why this error appears to my browser. I think my code doesn't have an error. Can someone know what is the mistake in this? I want the `$details` data displayed in a datatable.

Error that i get `DataTables warning: table id=datatable - Ajax error. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/7`

Controller

```php
 public function edit($id)
    {

        $item = User::where('id', $id)->first();

        $details = \DB::table('finances')
                    ->where('finances.user_id', $id)
                    ->orderBy('finances.id' ,'DESC')
                    ->get();

        // dd($details);
        return view('admin.pages.finances.show',[
            'mnuname' => $this->page_title,
            'page_title' => $this->page_title,
            'item' => $item,
            'details' => $details
        ]);

    }
```

Script

```php
@section('javascript')
//<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" ></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
//<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
    <script>
        console.log('asdasd');
        $(document).ready( function () {
            $('#datatable').DataTable({
                "processing": false,
                "serverSide": true,
                "ajax": "/finances/{id}",
                "type": "GET",
                "columns": [
                    { "data": "id" },
                    { "data": "description" },
                    { "data": "amount" },
                    { "data": "date" }
                ]
            });
        });
    </script>
@show
```

Route

```php
Route::get('finances/{id}', 'FinancesController@edit')->name('admin.finances.edit');
```

When i `dd($details)`

```
Collection {#555 ▼
  #items: array:3 [▼
    0 => {#541 ▼
      +"id": 5
      +"school_id": 1
      +"user_id": 11
      +"amount": "20"
      +"description": "Latest"
      +"date": "2019-11-15"
      +"created_at": null
      +"updated_at": null
    }
    1 => {#558 ▼
      +"id": 2
      +"school_id": 1
      +"user_id": 11
      +"amount": "1000"
      +"description": "New Payables"
      +"date": "2019-11-14"
      +"created_at": null
      +"updated_at": null
    }
    2 => {#549 ▼
      +"id": 1
      +"school_id": 1
      +"user_id": 11
      +"amount": "5000"
      +"description": "Old Payables"
      +"date": "2019-11-13"
      +"created_at": null
      +"updated_at": null
    }
  ]
```

Answer (score 0):

replace this

```
            "columns": [
                { "data": "id" },
                { "data": "description" },
                { "data": "amount" },
                { "data": "date" }
            ]
```

by

```
                  data : { "id": $("#id").val(), "description":                            
                       $("#description").val(), "amount":$("#amount").val(), "date": 
                       $("#date").val()} ,

                "columns": [
                    { data: "id" },
                    { data: "description" },
                    { data: "amount" },
                    { data: "date" }
                ]
```

Bind column with ids

Comment: bind columns with the `id` u have given in html

Comment: what do you mean by that sir? I am using table only.

Answer (score 0):

You should return json encoded data.

```
public function ajaxDatatableEdit($id)
    {

        $item = User::where('id', $id)->first();

        $details = \DB::table('finances')
                    ->where('finances.user_id', $id)
                    ->orderBy('finances.id' ,'DESC')
                    ->get();

        return json_encode($details);

    }
```

also make a function for your ajax and another function for your view.

```
 public function viewEdit($id)
    {

        return view('admin.pages.finances.show',[
            'mnuname' => $this->page_title,
            'page_title' => $this->page_title,
            'item' => $item,
        ]);

    }
```

on your route:

```
Route::get('finances/{id}', 'FinancesController@ajaxDatatableEdit')->name('admin.finances.edit');`
```

or if you're working with table you can use laravel datatables

Read documentation [here](https://yajrabox.com/docs/laravel-datatables/master/installation)

Comment: how could I insert that in my return statement? Is this correct ? `'details' => json_encode($details)`?

Comment: i dont want to use any package. I just use jquery ajax datatable. is this possible?

Comment: what do you mean by making another function sir?